# Degree over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

I'm kinda stuck with the following, I simply don't know how to calculate the following:

What is $\deg(\rho_7+\rho_7^2+\rho_7^4)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is $\rho_7$?

Comment: Do you know the Galois group of $\Bbb Q(\rho_7)$ over $\Bbb Q$?

Answer (score 1):

If (as I suspect) $\rho_7$ is a seventh root of unity, then what is
$(2(\rho_7+\rho_7^2+\rho_7^4)+1)^2$?